# Configuring Static replication agent in AEM6.1 author

Tags: aem

I'm trying to create file system of my website in my local machine and I have configured static replication agent in author following this http://www.wemblog.com/2012/02/how-to-use-static-agent-in-cq-wem.html document.
When I click activate on a page nothing is getting created in the target folder. In logs, it is showing NOTHING TO REPLICATE for all the pages.
I tried the same agent with geometrixx site and the content is created for it.
Help me with the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the rules for your content branch ? Static agent configuration allows you to define the rules on the 2nd tab (Rules).

By default only sample Geometrixx websites are configured

```
/content/geo* ${path}.html?wcmmode=preview
/content/dam* ${path}
/content/geo* /content/geometrixx/en.topnav.html
/etc/designs/* ${path}
```

Make sure to add /etc/designs/* ${path}