# GET JSON response from AEM

Tags: android, ios, aem

One of the requirements for our native mobile apps is to retrieve a config JSON that can easily be changed during production. For example, in our apps, we will hit up a URL that returns a JSON response containing features that the business wants enable, disabled or list of base URLs:

**GET** https://ourwebsite.com/mobile_config/

**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "enableFeatureA": true,
    "enableFeatureB": false,
    "baseUrls": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ]
}
```

To meet the requirement of it being configurable during runtime, we're planning to use a content management system, which has a publishing feature. We've recently been looking into AEM as our new publishing tool. My idea is to save a JSON file into the AEM content manager, and when a GET request is made to the URL, the backend will read the JSON file and return it as an 'application/json' content type. However, I can't find any obvious way to achieve the result of returning the contents of the JSON file when making a request using AEM.

Being fairly new to AEM, my guess is just create a jsp file to read the contents. But how do I return it? How do I manage the 'routes'? Do I need to set up a template? Is this the best approach?

Any guide is appreciated.

Comment: You can serve static files from [AEM](http://blogs.adobe.com/dekesmith/2012/05/22/place-simple-html-and-image-files-online-with-crx-and-cq/). A better solution might be though to store the data in the CMS & generate the JSON on the fly, [using a Servlet](http://blogs.adobe.com/aaa/2012/09/cq-tips-and-tricks-1-how-to-define-a-slingservlet-cq5-5-5-6.html).

Answer (score 0):

AEM reserves the use of .json as an extension; it uses it for RESTful views of content in a JSON format. You might have luck using a different file extension, such as filename.foo - but it'll probably give you the wrong mimetype unless you configure Dispatcher to fix this. This probably isn't the most considerate approach.

In short, if you upload a .json file into the DAM, you won't get what you expect. You'll end up with a path that looks something like /content/xyz/abc.json - but it'll render with the AEM JSON code, and give you the properties from the datastore instead of your file.

It is possible to turn off AEM JSON output, but it tends to break things as noted in the [Security Checklist](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security-checklist.html#Mitigate%20Denial%20of%20Service%20(DoS)%20Attacks). Besides it tends to be blocked in [Dispatcher configuration](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html) anyway most of the time (depending on local policy).

One approach, assuming that Dispatcher does allow JSON requests (or that you are able to permit this safely) is to [create a JSON.jsp](http://adobeaemtips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/jsonjsp.html) a page or component, and have the JSON data as a property. This also can have side effects in the authoring interface, as the JSON can interfere with the edit dialogues.

I think the best option might be to use [static replication](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/02/how-to-use-static-agent-in-cq-wem.html) to publish the file onto a static webserver. This is done as a separate replication queue. There's a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736329/configuring-static-replication-agent-in-aem6-1-author) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something pretty much identical to what you are asking. I created a featureToggling AEM component to allow runtime authoring of specific features of standalone angular applications. The angular application looks to the JSON content stored for my featureToggle component as the app initialises and enables/disabled features based on the values stored.

The component itself is a multifield that allows me to add multiple feature types with a toggle switch to turn them on or off. The JSON for ALL AEM pages is actually exposed by appending .infinity.json to the end of the url. My angular app simply reads from and interprets the JSON on initialise then shows/hides features of the app.

EG: http://[mysite]/[featureTogglePagename].infinity.json